# Can F# discriminated union types use generics not defined in the type signature?

Tags: generics, types, f#

I'm new to F# and I'm trying to get something like this to work:

```
type transform<'a, 'b> = 'a -> 'b

type transformPipeline<'a, 'b> =
  | SingleStep of transform<'a, 'b>
  | MultiStep of (transformPipeline<'a, 'c> * transform<'c, 'b>)
```

This currently doesn't compile, it says `The type parameter 'c is not defined`. All I'm trying to do here is chain together these pipelines so that I'm guaranteed the intermediary type `'c` can be passed to the transform on the right, but I can't figure out how to communicate this to the type system. Any ideas?

Comment: This is called "[existential quantification](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type)" and no, F# does not have those. I recommend that you model your domain differently.